# Creating tables and interaction plots from imputation results

Tags: r, interaction, imputation, graphing

I have run an imputation (woo!) and now I would like to create very nice tables and interaction graphs from the results. Though it doesn't seem that any of the traditional table and graph generating packages recognize the imputation results.

The error I'm getting is:

> could not access model information

Does anybody know of any packages that allow for specifically creating tables and graphs using imputed data?

Here's what I have so far:

```r
# Specification of imputation model 

fml <- RaceOrganized ~ 1 + RigbyFinal + TotalSessionsAttended + GradeLevel + RigbyEntry + FRL + StudentTeachRatio + AvgTeach + HomePov + PepDens + PercGreen + ( 1 | CDSCode ) + ( 1 | HomeCensusTract )

# running the imputation

imp <- jomoImpute(Imputation, formula = fml, n.burn=50000, n.iter =1000, m = 25, seed=1569)

# extracting the imputed data sets

impList <- mitmlComplete(imp, print="all")

# Fitting the model of interest with imputated data 

fit <- with(impList, lmer(RigbyFinal ~ 1 + RaceOrganized + TotalSessionsAttended + GradeLevel + RigbyEntry + FRL + StudentTeachRatio + AvgTeach + HomePov + PepDens + PercGreen + PercGreen:TotalSessionsAttended + ( 1 | CDSCode ) + ( 1 | HomeCensusTract ), REML= FALSE))
```

Then many failed attempts of creating nice apa tables such as [these](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/06/beautiful-table-outputs-summarizing-mixed-effects-models-rstats/) using "sjPlot" and interaction plots like [these](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interplot/vignettes/interplot-vignette.html) using "interplot".